# trying to get input from the d-pad, moving just one axis modifies both axis

Tags: input, unity-game-engine, joystick

I'll trying to get input from the d-pad of some joypad, assigning it to two axises. I'm trying both with saitek x-55 and saitek pro-fly yoke system.

Both of them, when move only up or only right, move both axis.

This is my configuration:

HorizontalView-> Joy2, Axis X, gravity:0 sensibility:1
VerticalView -> Joy3, Axis Y, gravity:0 sensibility:1

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: I bet the d-pad is not an axis but a 4x button. This is the standard behavior for many gamepads, ie you have a button for left, up, down, right on the d-pad.

Comment: Correct, this joystick has both 4x button classic d-pad, that unity look as 4 buttons, and also a "POV" d-pad that unity read only as axis.

I just try thrustmaster T-Flight Stick X that has some configuration but with it the "analog" d-pad appear to work fine.